# Running my asp.net 4.5 web application under visual studio 2012 will raise the following error:- HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, windows-server-2012-r2

I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 web application (using .net 4.5). and i am using Visual Studio professional 2012. now when i run the project inside VS-2012 i will get the following error:-

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
```

[image]

Although i am hosting the same application under IIS-8 and it is working well. but if i run the same web application inside Visual studio i will get the above error. i am using windows server 2012 r2.

can anyone adivce why my project is not working when i try running it inside VS? and this problem appeared all of a sudden i mean last week i was able to run the application without any problem..
Thanks

here is the event viewer errors regarding my problem , one related to iis-express, while the other related to VS:-

> An application has reported as being unhealthy. The worker process
>   will now request a recycle. Reason given: An error message detailing
>   the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the
>   application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry
>   to discover what caused this error to occur. . The data is the error.
>
> Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons:
>   there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file
>   is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or
>   the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2012 because of this error.
>
> Program: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 File:

Comment: Are you running VS in an elevated mode? "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: @BoydP now if i run it as an admin, and i run the project, my remote desktop connection will end and the vm will restart.. now what i did (based on the reply from Munam) i copied the whole project folder from its original location c:\users\admin\Visual Studio...\project\... to be under D:\ drive , then i clean>>build>run the project and it worked well.. so seems the problem is somehow related to running the project from the C:\ drive ! baring in mind that this problem appears all of a sudden,, as it used to work well last week.. maybe this problem is related to installing some windows updates

Comment: @BoydP but at the end i want my project to run from its original location at the c;\ drive ...

Answer (score 1):

Have u checked the "most likely causes". Possibly it is permissions issue. You may need to check startup project or you may need to review your web.config file

Comment: can you adivce what/ehere type of permission i need to check ?

Comment: i am currently i am an admin on the machine which is causing the problem

Comment: i try creating a new project but i got the same issue

Comment: Try creating project in different directory than c:\

Comment: now i move the new project to another drive D instead of C and it run correctly .. can you advice what does this indicate?

Comment: can you advice what could be causing the problem ,? now when i moved the project to be under D drive it worked well !!!

Comment: well, I can't tell you the exactly what causes the problem as I don't know your development environment. but seems like some issue with your iis. Are you using iis express that comes with visual studio ?

Comment: i think the problem is with iisexpress. because i am hosting the same application using iis-8 on the same server and it is working well. the issue i am facing is only when i run the web application from Visual Studio and the web application folder is inside the C:\ drive

Comment: Is it happens when u ctrl F5 in VS ?

Comment: yes exactly i can open and build the project without any problem, but when i run the project i will get internal server error.. and if i open VS as an admin and i run the project, then my remote desktop session will end and the dev machine will hang then restart!!!!